# How to receive all broadcast message?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want to know all broadcast message that occur at Android system or third-party application.

Broadcast messages that occur at Android system are so easy to know because make broadcast receiver, add intent-filter(all broadcast action) and receive :).

But messages that occur at third-party application are difficult to know because i don't know there broadcast message action :(

How to receive broadcast intent at third-party application?

Comment: I do not believe that there is a way to receive all broadcast messages. I struggle to see why the Android OS would want to provide a broadcast wildcard.

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to indiscriminately register for any broadcast event, but you can list all historical broadcasts and registered broadcast receivers with the following terminal command:

```
dumpsys activity broadcasts
```

Answer (score -1):

Essentially, you would receive only those broadcasts for which you have registered. It is not feasible/possible to receive all the broadcasts. In fact, if it is somehow possible, it would be a HUGE security breach !!!